# Is it possible to cancel dragging in react-native-draggable-flatlist when tabview switching started?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am using [react-native-tab-view](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-view). Inside it I have a [react-native-draggable-flatlist](https://github.com/computerjazz/react-native-draggable-flatlist).

The problem is that when I hold finger to start dragging and then swipe left - item still scaled until I tap on list again. `onDragEnd` or `onRelease` events are not called. How can I cancel dragging when tab switching started?

Here is short video:

[image]

Setup is very basic:

```
const TasksList: FC<TasksListProps> = ({ route }) => {
  const [dragging, setDragging] = useState(false);

  const onDragBegin = useCallback(() => setDragging(true), []);
  const onDragEnd = useCallback(
    ({ data }: DragEndParams<ListItem>) => {
      setDragging(false);
    },
    [todosStore, route.key],
  );
  // ... other staff
  return (
    <>
      <DraggableFlatList
        activationDistance={20}
        containerStyle={styles.container}
        contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}
        data={todos}
        keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
        onDragBegin={onDragBegin}
        onDragEnd={onDragEnd}
        refreshControl={
          <RefreshControl
            enabled={!dragging}
            refreshing={todosStore.fetching || listsStore.fetching}
            onRefresh={onRefresh}
          />
        }
        renderItem={renderItem}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        ListEmptyComponent={listEmptyComponent}
        ListFooterComponent={listFooterComponent}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

Whole App is wrapped with `GestureHandlerRootView` from `react-native-gesture-handler`